# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error in Django login function

Tags: django

I'm having problem in the built-in login function in Django.

Here is the views.py code:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid:
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)    
            return redirect('index')
    else: 
        form = AuthenticationForm() 
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

And below is my html code.

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

As soon as I click the 'Log in' button, it gives an error that says:
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

I don't see which part is wrong.
I very much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @kyore I am using a custom user model and this is the same error that pops up while serializing `user` object. Any tips?

Comment: @ruddra solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`is_valid`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) is not a property, it is a function. So you need to call it like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

**Explanation:** As you are not calling that function, the `AuthenticationForm` is not [authenticating the user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L214) inside `clean` method. Hence you are not getting the `User` instance with `form.get_user()` method.

Comment: Man this really got a huge trouble off of me. Thanks a lot. :)